# treat "implicit declaration of function foo" as error

Tags: c, gcc

GCC gives a warning `implicit declaration of function foo`  when you use `foo()` before its declaration. Is there any GCC flag that would make treat this warning as *error* and stop compilation? Sometime it would save you some debugging work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-Werror` will treat *all* warnings as errors.  You can be more specific with
`-Werror-implicit-function-declaration`